# NodeJS with express: res.get() returns always undefined

Tags: node.js, express, http, etag

I'm using Express.js 4.17.X and trying to use **res.get()** function for getting response header values.

But this is always returning **undefined**

Tried cases:

- res.get('Content-Type')
- res.getHeader('Content-Type')

both returning **undefined**

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        const isFresh = fresh(req.headers, {
          'etag': res.getHeader('ETag'),
          'last-modified': res.getHeader('Last-Modified')
        });
        if (isFresh) {
          // client has a fresh copy of resource
          res.statusCode = 304
          res.end()
          return
        } else {
          next()
        }
      })
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to get *response*-headers and not *request*-headers?

Comment: I'm trailing ETag with npm fresh module. So I need to get the response header values

Comment: I see - could you include your code?

Comment: Sure, Will update it in the question.

Comment: Having the same issue